# package.json forgot to --save some node module at installation

Tags: package.json

I have forgot to save some package in my package.json, not using --save when installed is there a way to find the missing package in package.json and to --save them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look inside `node_modules` and compare the directories to the ones in `package.json`. Then you can simply install them again. For example, if you see the `async` directory in `node_modules` and not in your `package.json`, you can just run `npm install --save async` again.

Comment: so no way to do it automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
npm install --save $(ls node_modules)
```